# Selenium XPATH Search for two values?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, appium, xcuitest

The element I am trying to search for looks like this:

```
//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Unseen. Notification (#REGJEWKOEW) Notification Alert System - Code RED githubstudent663"]
```

Now I need to search for "Unseen" notifications, as I only want new elements, nothing old that has already been "Seen". Alongside this, I want to search for notifications under my name of "githubstudent663".

```
//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=and contains(., 'githubstudent663')]
```

^Doesn't work. I'm also not sure how to get it working with two values, instead of just one?

Help is VERY much so appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//XCUIElementTypeButton[not(starts-with(@name, 'Unseen')) and contains(., 'githubstudent663')]
```